# handling dates in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I keep getting a syntax error as well as an identifying error at the `IF` statement.

```vb
Function Remove()

     Dim DateDue As Date
     Dim i As Long
     DateDue = Date

     For i = 2 To Sheets("MasterSheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        If DateDue = DateSerial(Year(Sheets("MasterSheet").Cells(i, 1)), 
                     Month(Sheets("MasterSheet").Cells(i, 1).Value),
                     Day(Sheets("Mastersheet").Cells(i, 1).Value)) Then
        msgbox(dnuanfdqduii)
        End If

     Next i

End Function
```

Comment: Your lines have next line inserted. Make sure you have that formula all on one line.  Paste this in: `If DateDue = DateSerial(Year(Sheets("MasterSheet").Cells(i, 1)), Month(Sheets("MasterSheet").Cells(i, 1).Value), Day(Sheets("Mastersheet").Cells(i, 1).Value)) Then`

Comment: If you want to break a line of code to multiple lines, you need to add a space then underscore at the end of each line (except the last). Read [this](https://excelchamps.com/vba/line-break/)

Answer (score 1):

VBA is sensitive to line breaks when you write a logical construction (like `If ... Then ... End If` in your case).

If you need to break a one line statement to two and more lines (for easy reading, for example), you need to use the VBA's Line-Continuation character `_` for saving logical sense.
It is reserved underscore character to continue a statement from one line to next.

So, your code:

```
If DateDue = DateSerial(Year(Sheets("MasterSheet").Cells(i, 1)),
            Month(Sheets("MasterSheet").Cells(i, 1).Value),
            Day(Sheets("MasterSheet").Cells(i, 1).Value)) Then

End If
```

can be corrected as follows:

```
If DateDue = DateSerial(Year(Sheets("MasterSheet").Cells(i, 1)), _
                        Month(Sheets("MasterSheet").Cells(i, 1).Value), _
                        Day(Sheets("MasterSheet").Cells(i, 1).Value)) Then

End If
```

You can read more about this at the link:
[how to break and combine statements in visual basic сode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/how-to-break-and-combine-statements-in-code)